# add controller with gulp and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, controller, gulp

I'm new to AngularJS and I've started a project with a template called *rdas*. This template includes gulp, bower and node (with npm).

Maybe I have made some mistakes, but I need to create a new controller file.

**Code**

```
<tbody ng-controller="CONTROLLER">
          ....some html code....</tbody>
```

Where do I put my controller source file?

I've created a simple App in Angular a few days ago, and added my controller like so:

```
<script src="mycontroller.js">
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you should learn more about best practices, especially file structure. There are several great articles and I definitely suggest you the [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#folders-by-feature-structure) by John Papa. This link points to the *File Structure* section.

Comment: when i create my controller i put on controllers folder

Answer (score 0):

You have to create additional file called mycontroller.js which is in your depends on your root directory.

The file should have the following structure:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('CONTROLLER', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

More info you can read here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: i know this. but the controller can't run on gulp! :(

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your application's root path. If the controller.js file in a directory named controllers under the root path of your web application you have to write this directory name before script name like `<script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm sorry sir but i know html :)